# Double convert to Fraction

Tags: java, math, double, converters, fractions

I want a double convert value into a fraction (in Java).

Example: 0.33333 -> 1/3

I have many examples to Fraction found, but this does not help me.
The numbers are always between 0 to 1.

Has perhaps anyone have an idea?

Tahnks,

Comment: You should include a [mcve]

Comment: to be precise, 0.33333 is **not** 1/3. How much precision you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want the approximate fraction representation of a double value (like your example)

A simple way is to try denominators one by one:

```
double doubleVal = 0.33333;
double negligibleRatio = 0.01;

for(int i=1;;i++){
    double tem = doubleVal/(1D/i);
    if(Math.abs(tem-Math.round(tem))<negligibleRatio){
        System.out.println(Math.round(tem)+"/"+i);
        break;
    }
}
```

This prints `1/3`. If you set `double doubleVal = 0.6363636;`, it prints `7/11`.

You can change `negligibleRatio` to a bigger value if you want more succinct fraction result.